# ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED when using squid proxy for connection

Tags: selenium, docker, proxy, squid

I have a squid proxy container on my local Docker for Mac (datadog/squid image). Essentially I use this proxy so that app containers on my local docker and the browser pod (Selenium) on another host use the same network for testing (so that the remote browser can access the app host). But with my current setup, when I run my tests the browser starts up on the remote host and then after a bit fails the test. The message on the browser is `ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED` right before it closes. So I assume that there is an issue with my squid proxy config. I use the default config and on the docker hub site it says

`Please note that the stock configuration available with the container is set for local access, you may need to tweak it if your network scenario is different.`

I'm not really sure how my network scenario is different. What should I be looking into for more information? Thanks!